# PHP - Permission denied on directory created via SSH

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions

Under linux, using php 5.3

If I use mkdir in a php script to create a folder, then I have full access on this folder to add files or create folder inside it.

If I then login on the server via ssh, create a second folder, chown(recursively or not) to the exact same user:group as the one created by the php mkdir(), and chmod it to the the same exact permissions as the first folder then trying to access this folder to add a file or create a new folder inside it will throw a permission denied.

Trying to chmod 777 does not work either. I cannot for the life of me figure out the difference between the two :

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 amadeous psacln     4096  6 oct.  02:38 test
drwxr-xr-x.  2 amadeous psacln     4096  6 oct.  02:39 testtest
```

Any idea appreciated.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**
The apache user is running with the user amadeous in the group psacln.
mkdir() does create the new directory with this user and group
A exec("whoami") returns amadeous as well.
But still no go.

**EDIT 2 AFTER COMMENTS ABOUT SELINUX BY GUIDO**
ls -Z does give different results although I don't know what to make of it :

```
drwxr-xr-x. amateous psacln system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 test
drwxr-xr-x. amateous psacln unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 testtest
```

How do I go about fixing this ?

Thanks

Comment: Its because PHP is creating the folder with the www-data user

Comment: @Bolli He wrote _chown to the exact same user:group as the one created by the php mkdir()_

Comment: Are you doing the `chown` with `sudo`? Because ordinary users are not allowed to use `chown`.

Comment: @Barmar My bad. But he should try change the ownership to www-data to be sure this is not the problem. The 2 files looks exactly the same.

Comment: What confuses me is that the two folders have the same name. How did that happen? Are they in different parent directories? Maybe the problem is with the permissions there.

Comment: Thanks. This was a type the directories do not have the same name at all. I edited the question. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: It looks like a selinux labeling issue; which distribution of linux? try to run `ls -Z` and report the results

Comment: Hey  Guido, could be the problem, ls -Z shows difference. Any idea of how to fix that ? Thanks

Comment: yes it looks it is that. Which distro? on centos/fedora you would use `chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t <directory>`. with httpd_sys_clntent_t being the content available for the httpd processes.

Comment: Hey guido, please add your comment as an answer. It worked perfectly. I'll give you the karma points :D Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right labeling for files and directories accessible from the httpd apache processes is
[`httpd_sys_content_t`](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache); while the files generated have `user_tmp_t`:

```
ls -Z
drwxr-xr-x. amateous psacln system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 test
drwxr-xr-x. amateous psacln unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 testtest
```

To fix the labeling, run ([more info](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-0f6390ddacfab39ee973ed8018a32212c2a02199)):

```
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t <directory>
```